# How many numbers repeat in a file

Tags: combinatorics

> I have file with $10^4$ keys. Every key is from $[0, 10^6).$ How many keys have duplicates on average?

I think this is the same as ask to put $10^4$ balls into $10^6$ urns and then ask how many urns contain more than one ball.

EDIT:

For now i started with the following process: I count expected number of urns with one ball $k$-th balls were used. Say, we have $U$ urns and $B$ balls.

\begin{align*}
E_1 &= 1\\
E_2 &= E_1 + \frac{U-1}{U}\\
E_3 &= E_2 + \frac{U - E_2}{U} = E_2 + \frac{(U-1)^2}{U^2}\\
E_4 &= E_3 + \frac{U - E_3}{U} = E_3 + \frac{(U-1)^3}{U^3}\\
\dots\\
E_B &= \sum_{k=0}^{B-1}\frac{(U-1)^k}{U^k}
\end{align*}

Ok, now i want to find expected number of empty urn. Probability that an urn stays empty is $\left(\frac{U-1}{U}\right)^B$. So, expected number of empty urns is $E(Z) = U\left(\frac{U-1}{U}\right)^B$.

Thus, number of urns with more than one ball is $U - E_B - E(Z)$.

*Thanks to antkam i see that i calculate $E_i$ in a wrong way.*

Comment: Hint:  use indicator variables.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the hint, i concocted a solution. Could you take a look, please and advise me further?

Comment: In $E_2 = E_1 + \frac{U-1}{U}$, wouldnt $E_2$ be the expected no. of non-empty urns (i.e. with _at least_ 1 ball) after 2 balls are placed?  If you really want $E_2$ to be the expected no. of urns with _exactly_ 1 ball, then in the $\frac{1}{U}$ case of duplicate, $E_2$ should be 0.

Comment: @antkam Thanks! You are right. Now it is complicated again:(

Comment: I imagine what @lulu meant was to use an indicator that directly indicates if a certain Urn has more than 1 ball...

Comment: @antkam exactly.  Let $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ urn has more than one ball, and $0$ otherwise.  Then $E[X_i]=1-P_0-P_1$ where $P_j$ denotes the probability that a specified urn contains exactly $j$ balls.  It is easy to compute both.

Comment: @lulu, please move your comment to an answer and i will accept. No need to provide any additional calculations. Thanks!